# Merging two dataframes deletes some of the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, which look like this:
#1

```
Approved symbol RefSeq IDs  Ensembl gene ID
A1BG    NM_130786   ENSG00000121410
A1BG-AS1    NR_015380   ENSG00000268895
A1CF    NM_014576   ENSG00000148584
A1S9T       
A2M NM_000014   ENSG00000175899
A2M-AS1 NR_026971   ENSG00000245105
```

#2

```
Approved symbol RefSeq IDs  Ensembl gene transcript ID
DDX11L1 NR_046018   ENST00000456328
DDX11L1     ENST00000456328
DDX11L1     ENST00000518655
OR4F5   NM_001005484    ENST00000335137
DQ597235        n/a
DQ599768        n/a
```

*These are not the whole dataframe, just the head.*

What I wanted to do was to merge both files according to the first column so I executed the following commands:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('human_conversion_by_gene_symbol', sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv('human_conversion_transcript', sep='\t')

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Approved symbol'])

df3.to_csv('merged_human_conversion', sep='\t')
```

The problem starts now, I don't seem to find some of the values I find in the original dataframes.
For example, I'm searching for `MIR4430` (which belongs to the first column) and I'm able to find it in `df1` but not in the merged dataframe.
Doesn't merge supposed to take the union of elements inside the column I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define merging type using `how` argument passed to `pd.merge` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). It is `inner` by default. If you want the union, set `how = 'outer'`.

Answer (score 1):

`merge` command by default uses `inner` merge (only include items that exist in both dataframes).

you would need to use `outer` merge to do the union

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Approved symbol'], how='outer')
```

refer to the [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) docs